# How would I simplify my definite integral properly?

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals, solution-verification

Original equation $$\int_1^3\frac{1}{x^2-2x+5}\mathrm{d}x$$
Here is what I did starting with completing the square.$$(x^2-2x)+5\\(x^2-2x+1)+5+1\\(x-1)^2+6$$Then i plugged in back into the integral to use one of the inverse trig identities specifically tangent.$$\frac{1}{6+(x-1)^2}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\mathrm{tan}^{-1}(\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{6}})$$Then i plugged in my limits.$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\mathrm{tan}^{-1}(\frac{3-1}{\sqrt{6}})-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\mathrm{tan}^{-1}(\frac{1-1}{\sqrt{6}})$$
So how would I go on to simplify further than this?$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\mathrm{tan}^{-1}(\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}})$$

Comment: There is nothing left for simplification.

Comment: just a correction: $x^{2}-2x+5=\left( x-1 \right)^{2}+4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_1^3\frac{1}{x^2-2x+5}dx$$
$$=\int_1^3\frac{1}{(x-1)^2 + 4}dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(u)\bigg|_0^1$$
$$= \frac{\pi}{8}$$

I left a lot out here, but I assume you can fill in the missing steps
Edit: I messed up a bit myself, fixed it though!

Answer (score 1):

$x^{2}-2x+5=\left( x-1 \right)^{2}+4$ and after simplification you'll get $\frac{\pi }{8}$ as the answer to the integral